# Android app fails to connect with MySQL database

Tags: java, android, mysql, retrofit

I have a .sql database which I edit using PHPmyadmin and a android app that retrieves the login credentials from the database and tries to login to the app according to the user's credentials. But it keeps showing "Unable to login" error in the app even though I use the correct credentials from the database, which in this case is phoneno and password. The Login_Activity.JAVA is as below. Why is the app not logging in properly?

**Login_Activity.java**

```
package com.example.ankit.mrestro.Controller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushConstants;
import com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushManager;
import com.squareup.otto.Subscribe;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.BusProvider;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.LoginEvent;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.LoginSuccessEvent;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.Bus.PushRegisterEvent;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.R;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.model.LoginResult;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.services.DataService;
import com.example.ankit.mrestro.services.RESTrepository;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_ID = "cust_id";
    public static final String PREF_TOKEN = "accessToken";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_DB_NAME = "loginResult";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public static Intent createIntent(Context c) {
        return new Intent(c, LoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DataService.init();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        /**
         * Check either we are already logged in
         */
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_DB_NAME, 0);
        if (sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_TOKEN, "").length() != 0) {
            RESTrepository.setToken(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_TOKEN, ""));
            RESTrepository.setUser_id(sharedPreferences.getInt(PREF_ACCOUNT_ID, 0));
            goToMainActivity();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        PushManager.startWork(getApplicationContext(), PushConstants.LOGIN_TYPE_API_KEY,
                "hwfeocSIPlgKTasIuARPREnS");
        //SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("pushService",0);
        //String userId=preferences.getString("user_id","no data");
        //Toast.makeText(this,"user id is:"+userId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Button loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String phoneno=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String password=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

                //      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"login..."+phoneno+"..."+password,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.show();
                BusProvider.get().post(new LoginEvent(phoneno,password));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        BusProvider.get().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        BusProvider.get().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onLoginSuccessEvent(LoginSuccessEvent loginSuccessEvent){
        progressDialog.hide();
        LoginResult result=loginSuccessEvent.getResult();
        if (result != null) {
            //  Toast.makeText(this,result.getCust_id()+result.getCust_name()+result.getCust_access_token(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            preferences.edit().putString(PREF_TOKEN,result.getCust_access_token()).commit();
            preferences.edit().putInt(PREF_ACCOUNT_ID,result.getCust_id()).commit();
            SharedPreferences pushPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("pushService",0);
            BusProvider.get().post(new PushRegisterEvent
                    (result.getCust_id(),result.getCust_access_token(),pushPreferences.getString("user_id","")));
            goToMainActivity();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to login, please retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void goToMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest you are connecting to a mySQL database, and there are many reasons why that isn't done in practice. Instead, it appears you are using a REST api to get to your database, and there are many points of failure. There's not enough information here to help you.

Comment: Check if your app is sending the correct request, check if the server receiving the correct request, check what is the response from the server, check if the app receive the correct response from the server.

Comment: @Bik How you are connecting you app to database ? Are you running this on a localhost ?? Provide us full information to help you.

Comment: @Lokesh yes I'm running the database on a localhost using wampp, phpmyadmin.

Comment: @frz3993 What is the process for checking all of that?

Comment: @323go Please explain the points of failure. I want to provide you more information, can we take this to chat?

Comment: This is an example, if you use post request from the app, write the query string to the logcat and check.At the server dump the query into the error log, see if the request is correct. Then at the app write the response from the server to logcat, if the server spout any error it will be seen.

Comment: @frz3993 I'm not quite getting it, will you help me via teamviewer please?

Comment: @Blk, if you don't even know what the points of failure are, you're in way over your head. Your question is much too broad. It's out of scope for folks on Stackoverflow to provide you with a crash-course on connectivity, or to architect your solution for you, or to troubleshoot those bits you found into a workable app.